# How to count current week publish node by specific user in drupal

Tags: drupal, count, nodes, content-type

How to count current week publish node by specific user in drupal for specific content-type ?

Comment: What version of Drupal are you running? My answer assumes 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
// select the number of nodes that is of a specific content type and
// were created this week by the named user
function <theme>_post_count($user_name, $content_type) {
   $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) node_count FROM {node} n
             INNER JOIN {users} u ON u.name = :user_name && u.uid = n.uid
             WHERE n.type = :content_type && 
             WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.created)) = WEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())";

   $result = db_query($query, 
                      array(
                        ':user_name' => $user_name,
                        ':content_type' => $content_type
                      ))->fetch();

   return $result->node_count; 
}
```

You could easily modify the above query to take a `uid` instead of a user name and so on.

You would then call this function like this:

```
print 'Articles added by admin during this week: '.<theme>_post_count('admin', 'article');
```